# Getting Error while trying to run sample python app

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, grpc

I just want to run it on 1 vm to access it via the web interface (8080):
List of what I did: created vm (debian 9) defaul service account google.
After that, I executed the commands according to the instructions
provided by Google:

```
curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/install-logging- agent.sh 
sudo bash install-logging-agent.sh
apt-get update apt-get install -yq git supervisor python python-pip
pip install --upgrade pip
virtualenv useradd -m -d /home/pythonapp pythonapp
export HOME=/root
git clone -b steps https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-python.git
/opt/app virtualenv -p python3 /opt/app/gce/env
source /opt/app/gce/env/bin/activate
/opt/app/gce/env/bin/pip install -r /opt/app/gce/requirements.txt 
chown -R pythonapp:pythonapp /opt/app 
# Put supervisor configuration in proper place
cp /opt/app/7-gce/python-app.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/python-app.conf
cat >/etc/supervisor/conf.d/python-app.conf << EOF
[program:pythonapp]
directory=/opt/app/7-gce
command=/opt/app/7-gce/env/bin/honcho
start -f ./procfile worker bookshelf autostart=true autorestart=true user=pythonapp environment=VIRTUAL_ENV="/opt/app/7- gce/env",PATH="/opt/app/7-gce/env/bin",\
 HOME="/home/pythonapp",USER="pythonapp" stdout_logfile=syslog stderr_logfile=syslog
EOF
supervisorctl reread
supervisorctl update
```

also i edited file config.py:

```
    import os
    SECRET_KEY = 'secret'
    DATA_BACKEND = 'datastore'
    PROJECT_ID = 'soy-channel-319506'
    CLOUDSQL_USER = 'root'
    CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD = '1111'
    CLOUDSQL_DATABASE = 'bookshelf'(created)
    CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME = 'soy-channel-319506:us- 
    central1:bookshelfmysql'
    CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET = 'bookshelfstorage1'(created)
    MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH = 8 * 1024 * 1024
    ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])`
```

Comment: Please add more detail to your question explaining what you're doing so that we may help. The bookshelf app comprises several services including App Engine and Firestore. I'm unclear why you're using supervisord. The error suggests that the credential(s) being used aren't authorized. It's possible the code is running under the VM's service account and, if so, by default this won't have permissions to e.g. write to Firestore. But, it's unclear what you're trying to do and how you're doing it and so difficult to answer

Comment: thanks for answer, just edited to tell what i actuallt want

Comment: You said you got an error, but nowhere in this message do you tell us what the error was, nor where you got it.  You don't think that might be necessary?

Comment: Your script is a mess.  I have tried to untangle it by inserting newlines where I think they go, but you should check it.

Comment: thanks for answer, Tim.  my script straight from https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/getting-started/getting-started-on-compute-engine#linuxmacos

Comment: I'll have a look at this question presently. Your original question included an auth error. You'll want a service account for the service with suitable permissions. I think that's probably the outstanding issue.

Comment: Ok, I spent more time on this than I expected. I'm unfamiliar with `honcho` and `supervisor` and this makes it challenging for me. Following the instructions, I was able to get a service working but it's using the `main.py` in `gce` directory not `bookshelf`. I am unsure how to configure it to use a `procfile` that references the `bookshelf` app instead of the one in `gce`.

Comment: The `config.py` file appears to be related to the Kubernetes deployment and so is a red-herring for you, I think. Unless you're deploying Kubernetes to the VM, you should ignore that directory.

Comment: I copied the `python-app` and `procfile` from `./gce` to `./bookshelf`, tweaked the `startup-script.sh` and am trying to ensure that `supervisor` uses those (suitably reconfigured).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have it working. The Bookshelf sample uses Firestore and does not use Cloud SQL. The configuration is confusing `./gce` and `./bookshelf` etc. but the following works for me.

`startup-script.sh`:

```sh
# Install Stackdriver logging agent
curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/install-logging-agent.sh
sudo bash install-logging-agent.sh

# Install or update needed software
apt-get update
apt-get install -yq git supervisor python3-pip python3-venv

# Account to own server process
useradd -m -d /home/pythonapp pythonapp

# Fetch source code
export HOME=/root
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-python.git /opt/app

# Python environment setup
python3 -m venv /opt/app/gce/env
source /opt/app/gce/env/bin/activate

# `grpcio` requires upgraded `pip`/`setuptools`
/opt/app/gce/env/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
/opt/app/gce/env/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
/opt/app/gce/env/bin/python3 -m pip install honcho

# Add `requirements.txt` from `bookshelf`
/opt/app/gce/env/bin/python3 -m pip install --requirement /opt/app/bookshelf/requirements.txt

# Move supervisor conf and procfile
cp /opt/app/gce/python-app.conf /opt/app/bookshelf
cp /opt/app/gce/procfile /opt/app/bookshelf

# Edit python-app.conf to reflect `bookshelf` directory
sed --in-place 's|directory=/opt/app/gce|directory=opt/app/bookshelf|g' /opt/app/bookshelf/python-app.conf

# Set ownership to newly created account
chown -R pythonapp:pythonapp /opt/app

# Put supervisor configuration in proper place
cp /opt/app/bookshelf/python-app.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/python-app.conf

# Start service via supervisorctl
supervisorctl reread
supervisorctl update
```

For GCP:

```sh
BILLING=...
PROJECT=...
REGION=...   # Firestore location
ZONE=...     # VM location
INSTANCE=... # VM instance name
ACCOUNT=...  # Service Account name
FIREWALL=... # Firewall rule name

# Enable services
for SERVICE in "appengine" "compute" "datastore" "firestore"
do
  gcloud services enable ${SERVICE}.googleapis.com \
  --project=${PROJECT}
done

# Or Compute Engine default
gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--display-name="Python Bookshelf VM" \
--description="Used by Python Bookshelf VM to access DB" \
--project=${PROJECT}

EMAIL=${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com

# Minimally logging, datastore.user
for ROLE in "roles/compute.imageUser" "roles/datastore.user" "roles/logging.logWriter"
do
  gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
  --member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
  --role=${ROLE}
done

# Create Firestore
gcloud app create \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud firestore databases create \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Create VM w/ `startup-script.sh`
gcloud beta compute instances create ${INSTANCE} \
--machine-type=f1-micro \
--image-family=debian-10 \
--image-project=debian-cloud \
--metadata-from-file=startup-script=${PWD}/startup-script.sh \
--service-account=${EMAIL} \
--scopes=userinfo-email,cloud-platform \
--tags=http-server \
--zone=${ZONE} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Check status
# Either
gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output ${INSTANCE} \
--zone=${ZONE} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Or
gcloud compute ssh ${INSTANCE} \
--zone=${ZONE} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# And
sudo journalctl \
--unit=google-startup-scripts.service \
--follow

# Configure Firewall
gcloud compute firewall-rules create ${FIREWALL} \
--allow=tcp:8080 \
--description="Allow port 8080 access to VMs tagged http-server" \
--source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 \
--target-tags=http-server \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

Then:

```sh
IP=$(\
  gcloud compute instances describe ${INSTANCE} \
  --zone=${ZONE} \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --format="value(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)")

curl http://${IP}:8080
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for a great job and help, let me try,  but i really need to run "steps" branch with cloud sql

Comment: I don't have time to reconfigure the Kubernetes example so that it will run directly on a VM with Cloud SQL. Your `config.py` should use `cloudsql` not `datastore`. You'll need to configure the VM's service account to permit Cloud SQL access and you'll also want to use Google's Cloud SQL proxy to connect your VM to your instance. Good luck!